# Counter for Android Studio increments wrong

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe android app and I want the score to be kept. I have everything working except for the increment. For some reason, instead of going up by 1, it goes up by 2.

This is the method I use for when I'm incrementing the score and checking the game to see if there is a winner or not:

```
private Button one;
private Button two;
private Button three;
private Button four;
private Button five;
private Button six;
private Button seven;
private Button eight;
private Button nine;
private TextView winner;
private Button clearBoard;
private int scoreX;
private int scoreY;
private int tie;
private boolean turn = false; //determines who's turn it is

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    one.setText("-");
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box2);
    two.setText("-");
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box3);
    three.setText("-");
    four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box4);
    four.setText("-");
    five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box5);
    five.setText("-");
    six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box6);
    six.setText("-");
    seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box7);
    seven.setText("-");
    eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box8);
    eight.setText("-");
    nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.box9);
    nine.setText("-");

    scoreX = 0;
    scoreY = 0;
    tie = 0;

    winner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.win);
    clearBoard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame);
    clearBoard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            one.setText("-");
            one.setEnabled(true);
            two.setText("-");
            two.setEnabled(true);
            three.setText("-");
            three.setEnabled(true);
            four.setText("-");
            four.setEnabled(true);
            five.setText("-");
            five.setEnabled(true);
            six.setText("-");
            six.setEnabled(true);
            seven.setText("-");
            seven.setEnabled(true);
            eight.setText("-");
            eight.setEnabled(true);
            nine.setText("-");
            nine.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
}

public void game(View view) {
    Button b = (Button) view;
    moves(b);
}

public void moves(Button b){
    if(turn == false){
        b.setText("X");
        b.setTextSize(15);
    } else {
        b.setText("O");
        b.setTextSize(15);
    }

    //once X or O is placed, cannot reuse that button till new game
    b.setEnabled(false);
    b.setTextSize(15);
    turn = !turn;
    check();

    //if there is a winner, make it so buttons can't be pressed and new game   must start
    if(check() == true){
        one.setEnabled(false);
        two.setEnabled(false);
        three.setEnabled(false);
        four.setEnabled(false);
        five.setEnabled(false);
        six.setEnabled(false);
        seven.setEnabled(false);
        eight.setEnabled(false);
        nine.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public boolean check() {
    boolean finished = true;
    int player = 1; //1 is player X, 0 is player O, 2 is a tie
    //horizontal check
    if((!one.getText().equals("-")) && one.getText().toString().equals(two.getText().toString()) && two.getText().toString().equals(three.getText().toString())) {
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!four.getText().equals("-")) && four.getText().toString().equals(five.getText().toString()) && five.getText().toString().equals(six.getText().toString())){
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!seven.getText().equals("-")) && seven.getText().toString().equals(eight.getText().toString()) && eight.getText().toString().equals(nine.getText().toString())){
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!one.getText().equals("-")) && one.getText().toString().equals(four.getText().toString()) && four.getText().toString().equals(seven.getText().toString())){
        //vertical check
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!two.getText().equals("-")) && two.getText().toString().equals(five.getText().toString()) && five.getText().toString().equals(eight.getText().toString())){
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!three.getText().equals("-")) && three.getText().toString().equals(six.getText().toString()) && six.getText().toString().equals(nine.getText().toString())){
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!one.getText().equals("-")) && one.getText().toString().equals(five.getText().toString()) && five.getText().toString().equals(nine.getText().toString())){
        //diagonal check
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if((!three.getText().equals("-")) && three.getText().toString().equals(five.getText().toString()) && five.getText().toString().equals(seven.getText().toString())){
        if (one.getText().equals("O")) {
            player = 0;
        }
    } else if ((!one.getText().equals("-")) && (!two.getText().equals("-")) && (!three.getText().equals("-")) && (!four.getText().equals("-")) && (!five.getText().equals("-"))
            && (!six.getText().equals("-")) && (!seven.getText().equals("-")) && (!eight.getText().equals("-")) && (!nine.getText().equals("-"))){
        player = 2;
    } else {
        return finished = false;
    }

    if(player == 1){
        scoreX = scoreX + 1;
        winner.setText(String.format("Player X is the winner!\nGames won by player X: %d\nGames won by player O: %d\nNumber of ties: %d", scoreX, scoreY, tie));
    } else if (player == 0){
        scoreY = scoreY + 1;
        winner.setText(String.format("Player O is the winner!\nGames won by player X: %d\nGames won by player O: %d\nNumber of ties: %d", scoreX, scoreY, tie));
    } else if(player == 2){
        tie= tie + 1;
        winner.setText(String.format("It's a tie!\nGames won by player X: %d\nGames won by player O: %d\nNumber of ties: %d", scoreX, scoreY, tie));
    }

    return finished;
    }
}
```

My variables, scoreX, scoreY, and tie are all member variables and set to 0. I must be missing something because I just can't see how my variables are incrementing by 2 instead of 1. Please help!

EDIT: I know the coding isn't pretty. I'm still a beginner. I added in all of my code. I know especially my check() method is long, though I'm not sure how I could shorten the length of that as I am checking the buttons on the game board.

Comment: It's `if/else if` hell. Consider starting over with pen & paper

Comment: That code is a complete mess, but it doesn't increment your variables more than once each. You haven't shown us all the code yet. Add more. And, try removing some duplication (try removing it all in fact).

Comment: I know my code isn't pretty as I'm just a beginner. I added the rest of my code. Also, when I test it, it increments +2 instead of +1, even if the code looks like it's only incrementing once. That's why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are calling your check function twice: 
I can't really give you the line numbers but this is where it happens (in the moves function):

```
check();

//if there is a winner, make it so buttons can't be pressed and new game   must start
if(check() == true){
```

What you should do instead is save the result of your first check call and then use that:

```
boolean result = check();

//if there is a winner, make it so buttons can't be pressed and new game   must start
if(result == true){
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize that could have been the problem. I kept looking at my check() method thinking something was wrong in there. It now works!